# Calculating user input without eval and jQuery

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate the user's input but when I'm trying to do a quick addition it outputs *NaN=* instead of the actual result

The user should be able to click the buttons to do the math, the problem is that my code can't get the user input before the user did the math

e.g. = 
User input: 1+4;
*My code can't get the 1 or the 4 and can't do math*

Here is what I tried:

Code snippet :

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons")[0];

 buttons.onclick = (element) => {
  if (element.target.className != "buttons") {
   if (element.target.innerHTML == "=") {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.innerHTML.length; i++) {
     if (buttons.innerHTML = "+") {
      result.innerHTML = element.target.value + i; 
     }
    }
   }
   result.innerHTML += element.target.innerHTML;
   console.log("User: " + element.target.innerHTML);
  }
 }
```

```html
  <div class="result">
          </div>
          <div class="buttons">
            <div>&larr;</div>
            <div>C</div>
            <div>%</div>
            <div>/</div>
            <div>7</div>
            <div>8</div>
            <div>9</div>
            <div>x</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
            <div>6</div>
            <div>-</div>
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>+</div>
            <div>0</div>
            <div>.</div>
            <div class="equal">=</div>
          </div>
```

I can't edit the HTML and use jQuery.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate since my numbers doesn't have any variables

Comment: your "numbers" are actually strings.. you need to parse them with: parseInt("your value", 10)

Comment: Why are you using divs? Form controls actually have calculation features baked in. I'd like to know in what circumstance you'd be in that you can't change a bunch of divs. BTW "numbers don't have variables"? Ok,  I wasn't aware that they ever could but vice versa certainly. Do not be afraid of `var` it is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here is that when you add the **text** contained in an element to the **text** contained in some other element the result is not a number NaN. Hmmm, well last I checked doing math on strings does not produce numbers. Maybe we should try some of javascript's string parsing functions that are designed to produce numbers? [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```
parseInt(result.innerHTML, 10) += parseInt(element.target.innerHTML);
```

Comment: I still get NaN=